Issue with Service User Permissions in Azure DevOps When Fetching Work Items by Custom Field
I am encountering an issue with service user permissions in Azure DevOps (ADO) that I hope someone can help clarify. We have an organization in ADO containing multiple projects. In our workflow, we utilize an API call to collect work items based on a specific custom field.
Previously, we authenticated these API calls with a Personal Access Token (PAT), and everything functioned as expected. However, after switching to a service user for authentication, we started facing a problem in one specific project ("Project B").
Issue: When attempting to collect a work item based on its custom field value ("custom_value") in Project B, the API does not return the correct items. Instead, it fetches work items with the same custom field from Project A. These items from Project A should not be included in the results for Project B. The service account has a Project Administrator role in Project B and it seems to be only appearing in this project.
The POST request:
https://dev.azure.com/org/ProjectB/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=7.0

The body:
{

"query": "SELECT [System.ID] FROM WorkItems WHERE [Custom.VersionforRMBot] CONTAINS 'custom_field' ORDER BY [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] ASC, [System.CreatedDate] DESC"

}

Could there be a specific configuration or permission setting within Project B that I might be overlooking?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Hi @NyestÁgoston, Welcome to SO. May I know what was the role of your service user in ProjectA? It seemed that your service user had access to the WITs from not only ProjectB but also ProjectA. Hope the answer below by Shamrai could work for you. Thx.

Hi @NyestÁgoston, Have you got a chance to check the answer by Shamrai below to add project filter? Hope it could resolve your concern in this thread. Thx and have a nice weekend.

Your query fetches work items across your organization (in all your projects).
"SELECT [System.ID] FROM WorkItems WHERE [Custom.VersionforRMBot] CONTAINS 'custom_field' ORDER BY [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] ASC, [System.CreatedDate] DESC"

In this case, your service account has access to all projects and always returns the same result. You may add a filter for the team project field:
"SELECT [System.ID] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = 'ProjectB' AND [Custom.VersionforRMBot] CONTAINS 'custom_field' ORDER BY [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] ASC, [System.CreatedDate] DESC"

Check this doc: Query language overview
